# I’m having trouble linking my CSS file to my html

Tags: html, css

I created the CSS folder and named it. I added this to my header in HTML but the changes aren’t happening.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="haiku-styles-shaun.css" />
```

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** and a **Network** tab. Please confirm: Is the resource _found_ (e.g. HTTP 200 response)? If not, which _actual URL_ is requested?

Comment: what is the CSS folder name you created? Include that folder name in the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_FOLDER_NAME/haiku-styles-shaun.css" />`

Comment: I did. It's still not linking.

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="haiku/app/haiku-styles.css/haiku-styles-shaun.css" />

Comment: what is the path for CSS file and HTML file?

Comment: `haiku-styles.css` is this a folder name or css file?

Comment: It is the folder name

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned you've created a CSS folder. Then include that folder name in the `href`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS_FOLDER_NAME/haiku-styles-shaun.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably your CSS file isn't in the same directory as your HTML file, you provided the wrong name of your CSS file (also check that your CSS file's extension is `.css`). Solve these and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include each file you need separately.

e.g.:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="haiku-styles-shaun.css/myButton.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="haiku-styles-shaun.css/myPhoto.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="haiku-styles-shaun.css/myFooter.css" />
```

Most user don't need all their style definition at the same time. To save bandwidth you have to choose.

Answer (score 0):

You said that you created a folder but you didn't write it on the path. Try adding the css folder before the file name like this:

```
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folder/file.css" />
```

Furthermore I suggest you to include versioning in your css to avoid browser caching when you refresh. To do that every time you update your css change the number at the end in the link:

```
 <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="folder/file.css?v=1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<link>` tag is used to link to external style sheets. You have to use something like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Folder-Name/Stylesheet-Name.css">
```

Make sure that your `href` address is setup properly otherwise it won't load in your HTML page .

**Note:** The  element is an empty element, it contains attributes only.
**Note:** This element goes only in the head section, but it can appear any number of times.

> In HTML the `<link>` tag has no end tag.
>  In XHTML the  tag
>   must be properly closed.